# Swig template shows output tag before rendering content

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, flux

I'm working on an isomorphoc react/flux app and use swig to render the content.
However, when I open the site it first shows a blank page with the `{{ html|safe }}` output tag, before rendering the actual content into my index.html file.

In my server.js the code looks like:

`res.status(200).send(swig.renderFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html', {html: html}));`

Any idea how i can prevent this? And also, does this prevent serverside-rendering? Does the google crawler see only the output tag when crawling the page?

Thank you.

Edit:

```
require('babel-register');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var compression = require('compression');

var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var swig  = require('swig');
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom/server');
var Router = require('react-router');
var routes = require('./app/routes');

app.use(compression());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// create react router
app.use(function(req, res){
    Router.match(
        {
            routes: routes.default,
            location: req.url
        },
        function(err, redirectLocation, renderProps){
            if(err){
                res.status(500).send(err.message);
            } else if(redirectLocation){
                res.status(302).redirect(redirectLocation.pathname +     redirectLocation.search);
            } else if(renderProps){
                var html = ReactDOM.renderToString(React.createElement(Router.RouterContext, renderProps));
            var page = swig.renderFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html', {html: html});
            res.status(200).send(page);
        } else {
            res.status(404).send('Page not found');
        }
    }
);
});
// and so on ...
```

And here is my routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import App from './components/App';
import Home from './components/Home';

export default (
    <Route component={App}>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    </Route>
);
```

Comment: Can you show more of the relevant code, specifically app.get from where the res.status... comes. Also is /public/ directory served as public?

Comment: Added more code. The propblem is not that it's not working, the problem is, that the user sees the swig output tag for 1 second before the content renders.

Comment: I understand, the thing is the swig tag `{{ html|safe }}` should never leave the server. It should never get to client since swig should replace it on the server. Add console.log('HTML', page) before `res.status(200).send(page);` is the swig tag still there? It should not!

Comment: Also if you require index.html from client it's probably not rendered by swig but simply served as static file by express.static

Comment: The problem seems to be that the "/" route is not serverside-rendered. `app.use(function(req, res){ Router.match... })`is not working on the root route. Just don't know how to fix this now.

Comment: Can you show your routes file (./app/routes)

Comment: Added into my post.

Comment: Try to change this line `routes: routes.default` in Router.match to `routes: routes`

Comment: You can also try console.log('routes', routes.default); it should output *routes undefined*

Comment: Does not help. It wont go into app.get / app.use on root route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index.html was the problem. Renamed it to "site.html" and now serverside rendering works on root route and no swig tags are visible.